# Python script only runs when using Open With.. in the windows context menu

Tags: python, cmd, windows-10

Using windows 10 and Python 3.8 running the following script called `Shutdown.py` via double-clicking repeats the output `Seconds to shutdown:`, However, if I open the script by right-clicking, Open with > Python (Python.exe not Pythonw.exe) it works succesfully. I've tried running as administrator.

```
import os

#CMD Request to time shutdown
minsToShutdown = input("Seconds to shutdown: ")
os.system('shutdown /s /t ' + minsToShutdown)
os.system('pause')
```

Screenshot (Note title bar):
[image: Screenshot of CMD]

Comment: There should be checkpoint "Use this as default", do you see it?

Comment: I have set python.exe as the default application for .py applications.

Actually, now that you mention it, this seems like a windows problem not a python one.